# Why Vim sets max text width to 79 instead of 80?

Tags: formatting

I'm a little puzzled about some default values in Vim.
In particular, for `gq{motion}`, is said that

```
[...]
If the 'textwidth' option is 0, the formatted line
length is the screen width (with a maximum width of
79).
```

I thought that it should have made more sense if it would have set the max width to `80`, instead.

Can someone enlighten me about this?
I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, `80` is a pretty arbitrary "standard" to begin with so… why not `79`? Now, wrapping lines at `79` in a `80` columns-wide terminal gives a bit more room to the right and *may* improve legibility. https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/472472898ab71ac80a86fedc37f8eb91461788dd/src/edit.c#L6737

Comment: Maybe, on `80` columns-wide terminal the last column was reserved for the wrapping symbol? Still, if you have line numbers on, then they will definitely take more than just one column. So, I'm still puzzled. Moreover, from the code you linked, is `79` the max value it can be used? Maybe I did not understand what I read.

Comment: ... or you can just set `textwidth` and be done with.

Comment: @VanLaser, haha, yes, of course, I've already done so. I was simply curious, and thought I was missing a main gotcha. There are always interesting historical justifications to these odd choices. Let's see whether someone knows better.

Comment: 80 is the number of columns of old hardware terminals, and later of MS DOS (text mode) screens.  `tw=79` instead of `tw=80` because displaying a line 80 characters long on an 80 columns terminal prints an extra newline.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: do you mean that the `<CR>` was visible and was the 81st character? This makes totally sense!

Comment: A newline is always added.  If it happens to be the 81st character on an 80 characters wide terminal you just get a full line followed by an empty one.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I don't know enough about terminal implementations to understand this explanation. Are you saying that an LF control character is not just something that tells the terminal to start a new line, but is also a character that is displayed (invisibly) on screen and therefore takes up a column of screen-space?

Comment: The cursor moves to the next when either (1) it's in the 80th column and a new character is printed, or (2) when a LF is encountered.  If both conditions happen at the same time, the cursor moves to the next line twice.  That's all there is to it: LF is an invisible control character, but it still counts as a new character when the cursor is at column 80.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Fascinating. At surface level, that seems an asinine implementation to me: do you know if there's a good reason for it, or was it just simpler that way? Does the cursor movement occur for *all* control characters? If a sequence of `BEL`s was sent would the cursor move across the screen as they were played?

Answer (score 11):

It is important to realize that this "default" only applies to the `gq` and `gw` commands and auto-format as described in that section.  The default `textwidth` is 0.  Furthermore, `:right` and `:center` default to 80, not 79.

As for why 79 was chosen, it cannot be a direct hold-over from vi since `gq`, `gw`, and auto-format do not exist in vi.  This is mostly speculation, but I believe the 79 default for auto-format was chosen for consistency with vi's existing auto-wrapping.  That this applies for `gq` and `gw` is a side-effect; one might expect 80 would have been chosen otherwise.

In vi (and in vim if `textwidth=0`) text starts auto-wrapping at the window width minus `wrapmargin`.  However, if `wrapmargin=0`, no auto-wrapping will take place. This means that if you were using an ADM-3A with an 80 character limit, with `wrapmargin=1`, the maximum width with auto-wrapping is 79.  An upside to this behavior is that there is a place for the cursor to live while waiting to see what the next character is going to be before deciding where to wrap.  Of course, vi and vim could put the cursor on the next line (as observed when typing a very long word) but leaving an extra column is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have any evidence that this is why 79 was originally chosen, but one good reason to *leave* it at that value is because if you use `'list'` with a value included for `eol` in `'listchars'` then the display of the listchar will cause an 80-character-length line to wrap onto the next line in an 80-character-wide terminal.

If the line is only 79-characters long, then the 80th column is free for the end-of-line `listchar` to sit in.

Comment: I didn't get it. Where am I supposed to use `'list'`? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Atcold It's an option that causes characters that are usually invisible (such as the end of line) to be displayed on screen. See `:help 'list'` or just try running `:set list` to see it in action.

Comment: `:set list` does not do much. I bet I don't have the `eol` in the `listchars`. I'm not very sure this is the reason behind the `79` characters. I believe @sato-katsura has the best answer in the comment.

Comment: `eol` is in `'listchars'` by default, but of course it's possible something in your config has removed it. I specifically state in my answer that I have no reason to believe that this was the historical reason that 79 was originally chosen. I'm just giving another reason why it continues to be a good value to use, now.

Comment: @Atcold. Newline is not displayed by default, it does not make sense to reserve an extra character for that.